# SQLAlchemy performance difference between engine and connection executio

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour with SQLALchemy from the performance viewpoint.
I've created this simple test script:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from time import clock, time
from datetime import datetime
import os

s = "Start: "+str(datetime.now())+"\n"
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///C:/mydb.db?check_same_thread=False")
print engine

ids = ('ecab910b-261b-11e9-9479-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab90f0-261b-11e9-8801-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab90f1-261b-11e9-bcf7-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab90f2-261b-11e9-a7c1-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab90f3-261b-11e9-b8d0-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab90f4-261b-11e9-8a61-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab90f5-261b-11e9-a11a-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab90f6-261b-11e9-9a55-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab90f7-261b-11e9-b16e-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab90f8-261b-11e9-82a6-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab90f9-261b-11e9-ad9d-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab90fa-261b-11e9-ae23-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab90fb-261b-11e9-93a5-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab90fc-261b-11e9-b963-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab90fd-261b-11e9-b875-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab90fe-261b-11e9-ae90-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab90ff-261b-11e9-8e07-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab9101-261b-11e9-8808-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab9102-261b-11e9-82e5-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab9103-261b-11e9-80e7-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab9108-261b-11e9-ad8c-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab9109-261b-11e9-80d0-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab910a-261b-11e9-9c5d-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab910d-261b-11e9-86f7-5800e3d291a6',
'ecab910e-261b-11e9-9322-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab910f-261b-11e9-b454-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab9114-261b-11e9-b1ec-5800e3d291a6', 
'ecab911b-261b-11e9-b40c-5800e3d291a6')

metadata = MetaData(engine) 
tab = Table("mytab", metadata, autoload=True)
q = update(tab, tab.c.id.in_(ids), {"status":5})

conn = engine.connect()
el = clock()
conn.execute(q)
s += "Elapsed (from connection) = %f\n" %(clock()-el)

el = clock()
q.execute()
s += "Elapsed (from engine) = %f\n" %(clock()-el)
print s
```

In the script I'm simply comparing the execution time when the query is executed from the engine and from the connection. Here is the output:

```
Engine(sqlite:///C:/mydb.db?check_same_thread=False)
Start: 2019-02-01 13:41:28.771000
Elapsed (from connection) = 0.007447
Elapsed (from engine) = 0.576755
```

Can anyone help me to understand why there is such a huge difference in the execution and what should be the right apporach to use SQLAlchemy with non-ORM  queries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide a complete example : mytab definition and size of the table/database. If I try to reproduce your example using mytabe(id: varchar(37), status:int) and just the record provided in code example, I have : Elapsed (from connection) = 0.001653 and Elapsed (from engine) = 0.001083 ... not the same results you have.
Furthermore, just one little loop over 28 lines seems quiet short to measure or try to figure performance problem.

Comment: You're right. I've been able to reproduce that on a tab having 67 rows with this definition: id: varchar(255), status:int. I've done that on a very small table to rule out the possibility that the number of records could somehow affect the overall performance, meaning if it's true for 67 rows, for bigger numbers it can only be worst...